# How to group firebase data in flutter with DateTime?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am making a chat application in flutter using firebase. I want to show a header with the date whenever the date changes. How can I group messages in flutter coming from firebase on the basis of date and show a header with the changed date?

I have tried GroupedListView package but I was not able to retrieve the chatmessages successfully.

Comment: Could you give more context? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.